# laravel validation rule out of fillables

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.4, rules

my rules and fillable array is below

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'cover', 'price', 'dumping', 'description'
];

protected $rules = [
    'title' => 'required|max:255|unique:packages',
    'price' => 'required|numeric|between:0.01,999999.99',
    'dumping' => 'sometimes|nullable|numeric|between:0.01,999999.99'
];
```

as u see above i have no attribute called slug in fillable so user can not fill this column as it want

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    if ( $model->id ){
        $this->rules['slug'] .= ',slug,'.$model->id;
    }

    static::saving(function($model){
        $model->slug = str_slug($model->title);
    });
}
```

> **but**

if i want to update a model, i must validate slug attribute use by title with

> str_slug($model->title)

i don't know how could i do this?

how can i this dynamic rule ?

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

i solved like this :

```
$data = array_merge($request->except('slug'), ['slug' => $request->has('title') ? str_slug($request->title) : '' ]);
$package = new Package();
if ( $package->validate($data) ){
    $package->fill($request->all())->save();
    \Session::flash('success', __('common.message.success.add'));
    return redirect()->route('admin.package.list');
}

protected $rules = [
    'title' => 'required|max:255|unique:packages',
    'slug' => 'required|max:255|unique:packages',
    'price' => 'required|numeric|between:0.01,999999.99',
    'dumping' => 'sometimes|nullable|numeric|between:0.01,999999.99'
];

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::saving(function($model){
        $model->slug = str_slug($model->title);
    });
}
```

in this way, i protect slug from other objects except using the title

have a nice day ... :)